# How to extract array on nodejs

Tags: arrays, node.js, api

Im making the api for showing the user info, so I write the code like this

```
res.json({"Status" : true , "User" : rows });
```

then i get the result

```
    {
      "Status": true,
      "User": [
        {
          "userid": 821786,
          "fullname": "undefined",
        }
      ]
    }
```

But I want the result like this

```
    {
      "Status": true,
      "userid": 821786,
      "fullname": "undefined"
    }
```

How can I do this ?

I tried

```
res.json({"Status" : true ,"Type":"Google",  rows });
```

but it gives me

```
    {
      "Status": true,
      "rows": [
        {
          "userid": 821786,
          "fullname": "undefined",
        }
      ]
    }
```

I can sure that only one result will be queried so i dont want to use array

Comment: Prepare code for response before putting it into `res.json` method

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
var result = rows[0];
result.Status = true;
res.json(result);
```